# Different ways of solve $\cos 4x - \sin 6x = 0$?

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

> How to solve $\cos4x - \sin6x = 0$?

My attempt was wrong so I deleted it.

Comment: How did you go from $\cos^24x-\sin^26x=0$ to $\cos(4x+6x)=0$? The only solution is $x=\pi/20$, not $\pi/10$, the latter isn't even in range.

Comment: @Luke yes you are right, I wrote it wrongly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's $$\cos4x=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-6x\right),$$ which gives
$$4x=\frac{\pi}{2}-6x+2\pi k,$$ where $k$ is an integer number or
$$4x=-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-6x\right)+2\pi k.$$
From the first we obtain:
$$x=\frac{\pi}{20}+\frac{\pi k}{5}$$ and we need to choose an integer $k$ for which
$$0<\frac{\pi}{20}+\frac{\pi k}{5}<\frac{\pi}{12}.$$
For the second case we can use the same reasoning.

Can you end it now?

Comment: @kvantour  It's a different way. No?

Comment: @kvantour no it is my question, I understand it

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$\sin6x=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-6x\right)\therefore \cos{4x}-\sin6x=\cos4x-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-6x\right)$$
$$=2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-5x\right)=0\implies\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-5x\right)=0$$
That should be reasonably simple to solve.